# Haskell - finding a string in a list by a prefix

Tags: haskell

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
ccc 1 1
bbb 2 2
aaa 3 3
```

I want to create a function that get an entire line by the first word like that:

```
f bbb = "bbb 2 2"
f aaa = "aaa 3 3"
```

I have written the following code:

```
    contents !! (fromJust (findIndex (name `isInfixOf`) contents))
```

Where `contents` is a list of strings containing the above text.
After reading the file and using these functions:

```
all <- readFile file
contents <- lines all
```

**It works** but it doesn't look so good.

Is there a more direct way to do function `f` (from above)?

I thought maybe `Data.List.find` or `Data.Text.find` could help but they don't seem to match.

Comment: I don’t completely follow, you want to use Text, because it has `find`? Because `find` is also in Data.List

Comment: I didn't know that, how can I then use find to do that?

Comment: you just need to drop the `contents !!` part

Comment: Why? Funciton f is what I want to acheive, not finding an index but getting the whole line.

Comment: You achieve what you want in an awkward and roundabout way. `findIndex` returns an index, then you go and traverse the list again to find the element that corresponds to the index. `find (name \`isInfixOf\`) contents` returns what you want directly, no need for `!!`. By the way what happens if the line is not found? Are you OK with your program crashing?

Comment: Yes I am fine with the program crushing. I know that it is roundabout which is why I asked here, thanks for showing me how to use find!

Comment: By the way again, are you sure `contents <- lines all` works?

Comment: Yes it works, it is in a do block and I tested it.

Comment: Yeah If it's not in the same `do` block with the line above it, then it could work. It's a bit confusing the way you express it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you filter lines on the prefix?

```
Prelude> contents = lines "ccc 1 1\nbbb 2 2\naaa 3 3"
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> f prefix = head $ filter (isInfixOf prefix) contents
Prelude Data.List> f "aaa"
"aaa 3 3"
Prelude Data.List> f "abc"
"*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

You can remove the `head` if you want all the matching lines (possibly an empty list).

If you want to use f many times, a map will have a better peformance, but only if you look for a line *given the first word of the line* (and not any prefix):

```
Prelude> contents = lines "ccc 1 1\nbbb 2 2\naaa 3 3"
Prelude> import Data.Map (fromList, (!))
Prelude Data.Map> m = fromList $ zip =<< (map $ head.words) $ contents
Prelude Data.Map> m!"aaa"
"aaa 3 3"
Prelude Data.Map> m!"abc"
"*** Exception: Map.!: given key is not an element in the map
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/containers/Data/Map/Base.hs:489:16 in containers-0.5.7.1:Data.Map.Base
```

Operator `(!)` will find the value in *O(log n)* vs *O(n)* in the list version.

Some explanation:

- `fromList` creates a map given a list of `(key, value)`
- `map $ head.words` takes the first word of every element in the list
- `(zip =<< g) contents` is equivalent to `zip (g contents) contents` (here: zip the first words with the lines)